# Writing to a File in Java

Tags: java, file-io

I'm really new to Java, and I can't write to a file for some reason, my code looks like this:

```
FileWriter fstream;
    try {
        fstream = new FileWriter(fileLocation);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
        log.info("test was supposed to be written to the file");
        out.write("test");

        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("File not created ", e);
    }
```

When I go to the fileLocation, I see my file, but it's empty. My log does say "test was supposed to be written to the file"

What could I be doing wrong here?

Thanks!

UPDATE: My FileLocation variable is a string:

```
private String fileLocation="/Users/s/out.txt";
```

I'm using a Mac

Comment: What if you try to also do fstream.flush(); fstream.close(); ?

Comment: You forgot to close the filewriter

Comment: Can you post the rest of your program and also what the value of "fileLocation" is when you run it?  Also, are you on Windows, Mac, or *nix?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried what you suggested, it didn't seem to make a difference

Comment: The code works for me. The underlying writer should be closed as well, when the BufferedWriter is closed, shouldn't it? Maybe there is a problem concerning access rights? Have you tried a folder where you have full access?

Comment: @starcorn, that doesn't matter. Closing the outermost wrapper is sufficient, even though I'd have done it in `finally`. The `flush()` call is also unnecessary since close already implicitly does that.

Comment: The accepted answer indicates that this is a problem that can not be reproduced (by someone running the test correctly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code is fine. Are you checking the right file location? Perhaps you had created the file you're checking before; while your program could be writing elsewhere.

Comment: You are correct, I am using Vaadin to make this file downloadable, so each time I downloaded it, it was empty, but the original file appears to have "test" in it. Thanks for the suggestion :)